# Did the D-Gray Man manga cease publication?

Tags: d-gray-man

Whatever happened to D-Gray Man? The manga just stopped... I want to know what happens to Kanda and Alan. Things were just getting crazy.

Comment: Which language are you referring to, Japanese, English etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The D-gray man manga has not finished yet. It is on hiatus once again for an indeterminate period of time. This most likely due to her illness, but there is no proof of this right now.

At the time of writing, on [Jump SQ site](http://jumpsq.shueisha.co.jp/rensai/), the series' status is displayed as 「一時休載」 which means something along the lines of "temporary non-appearance in print." and they will most likely announce the continuation there. In case you are not a fluent Japanese reader (like myself) you might just want to follow this forum thread by [manga helpers](http://mangahelpers.com/forum/showthread.php/43942-The-DGM-Hiatus-Thread/page47) They keep a close watch on sites such as Jump SQ and try to announce it in English A.S.A.P.