# What is the current serialization status of D.Gray-Man?

Tags: d-gray-man

I realize [this question](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/7555/did-the-d-gray-man-manga-cease-publication) has been asked before, but it was 9 months ago and more information has come out since. Here's the information I've compiled so far.

1. I've been searching on [DGM Hiatus Thread (Manga Helpers)](https://mangahelpers.com/forum/showthread.php/43942-The-DGM-Hiatus-Thread/page61)
2. I've also looked at the [Jump SQ Site](http://jumpsq.shueisha.co.jp/rensai/), but my Japanese is rather poor and I find it hard to navigate.
3. I've also been looking on [Katsura Hosino's Instagram](http://instagram.com/hoshino1000), not sure if it is verified that it's her's on not.
4. Finally I've also seen things on [/r/manga](http://www.reddit.com/r/manga/comments/2l7sry/dgray_man_manga_looks_to_be_returning_soon_after/) that say that it's coming back.

The problem I have is that I can't find anything definite. I also wouldn't care if it started back up in either Japanese or English, I would learn Japanese if it meant I was able to start reading D.Gray again! Just wondered if you guys knew about anything more about it. Anything would be appreciated! Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [this article](http://www.animenewsnetwork.com/news/2015-07-03/d-gray-man-manga-relaunches-in-new-jump-square-crown-magazine/.90043) dated July 4th, 2015 on Anime News Network (which I believe is a reliable source):

> Jump Square Crown will launch on July 17. The new magazine will publish Katsura Hoshino's D.Gray-man and Yasuhiro Nightow's Blood Blockade Battlefront Back 2 Back.

So D. Gray-Man is going to be serialized again, but it is going to be serialized as a quarterly manga, so it will be something like 4 chapters a year of about 100 pages each

Edit:- D Gray Man Chapter 219 has been released, 53 pages of content excluding the announcement, Color page etc.

Comment: I can deal with four chapters a year! As long as it's coming that's all I care about! I'm going to have to start reading from the begging again to relive all of the fun! I'm going to choose your answer, but I want to check things out too! Just want to read up on the subject some myself!